# In a list of dictionaries changing a specific value of a specific key from integer to string

Tags: python, json

My list of dictionaries:

```
my_dict1 = [{'id': 101, 'noob': False},
        {'id': 102, 'noob': True}]
```

I know that 101's name is Kate, how do I create a new list of dictionaries that reads:

```
my_dict2 = [{'id': 'Kate', 'noob': False},
        {'id': 102, 'noob': True}]
```

edit: I can't access the dictionary by it's index in the list, since I can't know in advance the order of the dictionaries

Comment: `for dct in lst: if dct['id'] == 101: dct['id'] = 'Kate'`?

Comment: mmmh, I get the warning "can't assign to operator / illegal target for variable annotation"

Comment: Try actually indenting it out on separate lines instead of the condensed form

Comment: you are right, my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to search for and change the corresponding dictionary in the list:

```
my_dict1 = [{'id': 101, 'noob': False},
            {'id': 102, 'noob': True}]


class NotFoundError(Exception): pass

def change_id(my_list, old_id, new_id):
    for d in my_list:
        if d['id'] == old_id:
            d['id'] = new_id
            return
    else:
        raise NotFoundError(f'Old id {old_id!r} not found')

change_id(my_dict1, 101, 'Kate')
print(my_dict1)  # -> [{'id': 'Kate', 'noob': False}, {'id': 102, 'noob': True}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Where `my_dict1` is a list of dictionaries, you can loop through that list with a for loop. You can then check to see if the corresponding value `101` is in the values of the dictionary at that specific index.

Keep a variable, initialized at 0, and increment it each time through the loop to track which index the current dictionary is located at. If `101` is found in the values of that dictionary, use the current value stored in the index variable to index into the list. You already know that the key is `'id'`.

Since you used the index to access the specific dictionary, you can use the `'id'` key to access the value in that dictionary. In addition, dictionaries are mutable, so you can direct change the value as follows: `my_dict1[index]['id'] = 'Kate'`

```
index = 0 #incremented variable
for i in my_dict1: #loop through list of dictionaries
    if 101 in i.values(): #check if 101 is a value
        my_dict1[index]['id']='Kate' # assign 'Kate' as a value to the id in the dictionary containing 101
    index+=1 #increment variable
```

Comment: good idea but I can't, as the list is a result of previous functions and I don't know whether the dictionary which features 101 is going to be the first or not

Comment: @N0PE I made some edits to the code, but it seems someone else answered as well.

Comment: Thanks, would you just please tell me about the last line? I am struggling to understand it

Comment: my_dict1 is a list of dictionaries. index=0 is saying that you're starting at the first dictionary in the list. If it does not find 101 in that first dictionary, it checks the next dictionary in the list and increments index by 1, to track that you you now at that second dict. If there were more dictionaries, that variable would keep track of which dictionary was currently being checked. If it does find 101, then it would take the value of index and use it to index into the list, use the key to access the dictionary, and replace the value. Does this help?

Comment: @double-beep Thank you, I edited the post and will keep that in mind for the future